# ClientBundle Resources Path in GWT

Tags: maven-2, gwt

I have a maven gwt project, and I'm using ClientBundle to package my image resources within the project. I would like to place the images in `/src/main/resources` as should be done in maven instead of `src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/client` as gwt wants.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thank you,
Sammy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it; I can place the image at `src/main/resources/com/mycompany/myproject/client` and it will be resolved correctly ;)

Comment: This solution does compile. But eclipse gives a error on the source location saying that it doesn't exists.
Any ideas?
Thank you.