# Where to put resources for ClientBundle in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to keep my static resources out of the class tree, but have them in the `src/main/resources` tree. Though they should be found using the same path as the java class, like:

package my.path.to;

```
class ResourceBundle extends ClientBundle {
  @Source("src/main/resources/my/path/to/ResourceBundle/myIcon.png")
  ImageResource myIcon();
}
```

Do I always have to write the `@source` path to reference them? Or can I somehow tell the `ClientBundle` to just look in the same dir as the java class, but just in the resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it will look in the same directory as your java class. I typically put my graphics in a sub package of the resorces package. This keeps my java clean and separated and I don't have to do absolute path. I believe the ../ relative path also works if you wanted to it that way but it seems more clean to me to put the images in a sub package of resources.

com.vf.client.resources
com.vf.client.resources.images
com.vf.client.resources.css

```
/**
 * Draggable cursor icon.
 * 
 * <br />
 * Example
 * 
 * <img src="images/cursorDragArrowSmall.png" />
 * @return ImageResource 
 */
@Source("images/cursorDragArrowSmall.png")
ImageResource cursorDragArrowSmall();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do not annotate your `ImageResource`s with `@Source`, the `ImageResourceGenerator`, via `ResourceGeneratorUtil.findResources()`, will use a 
path relative to the `ClientBundle` package, appending the method name and using a set of default extensions to resolve the `ImageResource` source path (the extensions are picked up in order: png, jpg, gif, bmp; see how `ImageResource` is annotated via `@DefaultExtensions`).

Hence, if you put your images into the same package of your `ClientBundle`, they will get resolved automatically, without even use the `@Source` annotation. If you have images with the same name but different extensions, the first one is chosen, according to the previous order.

I'm not a maven user, but [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027408/clientbundle-resources-path-in-gwt?rq=1) if you keep the same package structure also in the `src/main/resources`, your images will be picked up in the very same way. Never tried though.